# The command "python manage.py startapp (nameofapp)" doesn't work

Tags: python, django, command-prompt

I've created a basic Django website, and I can't create a new app by using commands such as "python manage.py startapp appname" or "admin-py startapp appname".

I'm learning it through a YouTube tutorial, and the author creates the app that way. Once he has typed this command, the appname appears in PyCharm, but in my case, it doesn't.

Neither `python manage.py startapp appname` nor `admin-py startapp appname` seem to work.

Comment: What happens when you run those commands in the terminal? Do you see the files appear in the file explorer but not in PyCharm? Sometimes PyCharm doesn't automatically refresh when new files are added and you need to collapse/expand the file list to see the changes.

Comment: Have you tried `django-admin startapp blabla`?

Comment: after your post  has been posted, yes i tried, and didn't work. I tried both in terminal and command prompt, moreover, every command i've been using is used in both places.Is there an idea how can  i expand the file list, i mean it actually gives no error; therefore, something happens(file addition), but out of my sight..

Comment: can you share the error you are receiving?

Comment: (myenv1) c:\Users\1\DjangoProjects\myproject1>django-admin startapp neww

(myenv1) c:\Users\1\DjangoProjects\myproject1>django-admin startapp bla

Comment: As it is seen, there is no error whatsoever; however, it doesn't appear in PyCharm either...

Comment: Actually, the files i've created have been appended in the folder they have to be in.

Comment: Same issue here, the solution from @HigorRossato solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer to your question is too late,
however, in case somebody searched about the same problem and found your question
here is the answe,
just put the appname between "" like in the following line :

```
python manage.py startapp "appname"
```

also sometimes you have to type python3 or based on the version of python yoy are having, instead of only python :

```
python3 manage.py startapp "appname"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will work:

```
django-admin manage.py startapp "appname"
```